# HPE redfish - boot unattended embedded diagnostics

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, boot, diagnostics

I am looking for a way to boot an unattended diagnostic on HPE Proliant G10 units and to execute a specified test within embedded diagnostics (in this case extensive system test).
So far i understand you can boot directly to embedded diagnostics through redfish however i can't find a way to attach more instructions to the boot command in order to when booted into embedded diagnostics, continue and execute extensive system test.

Does anyone know of any possible workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After i have been in contact with HPE regarding this issue and after they have checked internally it turns out that there really is not a built in way to do this. Once the embedded diagnostics is booted it no longer have any active connection to the iLO itself and can't take commands such as what to do once booted.

If anyone would find some innovative solution to this, please contact me :)!

Best regards,
Nuzvee